# How to gain access to a local user profile linked to a Microsoft account?

Tags: user-accounts, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-10, password-reset

Inspired by [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/691448/windows-8-1-change-microsoft-account-to-local-account-from-administrator-accou), but without all the clutter about bad coding practices.

On Windows 8 and later systems, you can log in using three types of accounts:

- Local user account
- Domain user account
- Microsoft account

Let's say you need to gain access to the user profile of an user which is not currently available and/or doesn't want do give you his/her password; let's assume you have full administrative access to the computer using another account, but being able to access the user's files is not enough: **you need to actually log in as the missing user** (for whatever reason).

In the first two cases, you can perform a password reset if you have proper admin rights (local or domain).

But what to do if the user has been using a Microsoft account?

And no, "call Microsoft and ask them for a password reset" is not an option, *even if you have the legal rights to do so*; you need to access the user's data *on this computer*, without impacting whatever online services or other computers he/she also uses.

Comment: The only way I can see it being possible is to remove the account (which leaves the profile) create a new local account and then change the profile path in the registry.

Comment: In a business environment?  Use domain accounts.  Seriously, if the user is managing their own account then I can't see any way forward on this?